# Terminal: segmentation fault 11 while reading file and counting the amount of vowels

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault

The terminal keeps saying: segmentation fault 11.
My code is:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    file=fopen("test.txt","r");
    int c;
    int vowelCount=0;

    while ((c=getc(file)!=EOF)) {

        if( c=='a' | c=='e' | c=='i'| c=='o' | c=='u')
        {

            vowelCount++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d",vowelCount);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try debugging your program

Comment: Also you need to check if `file == NULL` after doing `fopen` but before doing `getc`

Comment: You're leaking a file handle - you never close the file.

Comment: Probably you will get better results by changing `(c=getc(file)!=EOF)` to `(c = getc(file)) != EOF` although that would not cause a segfault

Comment: @chux: the `#include <stdio.h>` is only missing from the code shown in the question; the code can't compile without something to define `FILE *` validly.  The only reason to core dump in the code is failing to open the file and then using the null pointer in `getc()`.  Once that's tested for, then the code will never find any vowels because `c` will be `1` on each pass through the loop (fixed by sorting out the assignment and comparison and parentheses in the condition).  The final `printf()` should include a newline, of course.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler The first sentence is a good insight to my comment.  The rest seems less appropriate to my comment and would have been a good foundation for your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your code:

- You parenthesized your loop condition incorrectly - it should be `while ((c=getc(file))!=EOF)`
- You used `|` instead of `||` inside the `if` condition
- You did not check the return value of [`fopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html): if the function fails because the file is not there or for any other reasons, it returns `NULL`. Trying to pass that `NULL` to `fgetc` leads to a crash.

It is the last item that is probably leading to the crash. Make sure that the file `test.txt` is in the directory in which you are running your program.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/7KMSMM)

Comment: Curiously, although the `|` instead of `||` is not a good idea, it doesn't affect the correctness of the result; it just results in unnecessary code being executed.

Answer (score 1):

check if file == NULL.

```
file=fopen("test.txt","r");
if (file == NULL) {
    return -1;
}
```

This could very much happen if file is not present in the current directory. So specify the path of the file correctly from where exactly you need to read the file.

For example:

```
file = fopen ("/home/xpeng/test.txt", "r");
```

Make sure that the file exists.

Then it should be all right.